# How to handle darkmode with Tailwind AND Mantine

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, darkmode, mantine

I'm building a React / Redux app combined with some styling libraries. By looking at the documentation of both [Mantine](https://mantine.dev/guides/dark-theme/) and [TailwindCSS](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode), I found pages treating about how to make darkmode / lightmode work in the app for each of them.

As I understand, Tailwind will use a class that we have to append and remove from the `<html>` tag of the webpage. While Mantine asks us to wrap our application inside the `MantineProvider` with the `colorScheme` property defined.

But... does that mean that my darkmode / lightmode switchers will have to change both of this values (the `<html>` class, and the `colorScheme` property) ? Is there a better way to handle this ?

Answer (score 0):

As per tailwind docs
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode#customizing-the-class-name
Some frameworks (like NativeScript) have their own approach to enabling dark mode and add a different class name when dark mode is active.

You can customize the dark mode selector name by setting darkMode to an array with your custom selector as the second item:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  darkMode: ['class', '[data-mode="dark"]'],
  // ...
}
```

As Mantime uses --> data-mantine-color-scheme
When MantineProvider is mounted, it sets data-mantine-color-scheme attribute on `<html />` element to the value that the user has selected previously or to the value of defaultColorScheme prop. data-mantine-color-scheme attribute is used in all components styles to determine which colors should component use.
https://mantine.dev/theming/color-schemes/#data-mantine-color-scheme-attribute

So combining info from both docs refereces , here is(tailwind.config.js) how I mananaged to get enable dark versions using tailwind utility classes

```
    /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
    module.exports = {
    darkMode: ['class', '[data-mantine-color-scheme="dark"]'],
    content: [
     './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
     './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
     './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
     ],
    corePlugins: { preflight: false },
   theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Now in our components, we can use something like

```
    import { Button, Group, Input } from '@mantine/core';
import mycomponent from './MyComponent.module.css';

export function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <>
      <Group>
        <h1 className={mycomponent.heading}>MyComponent</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <Button className="dark:bg-red-400">Button</Button>
        <Input placeholder="Heys"></Input>
      </Group>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As mantine library is used, so it makes sense to manage the theme using that library's approach.

However, we also want to use some theming features from "tailwind" related to colors. To make it work together, we can simply create root variables & map them to mantine colors.

By doing this, we'll be able to maintained the design from one central location.

To make this happen, follow these steps:

1. Define root variables in MantineProvider theme prop [https://v6.mantine.dev/styles/global-styles/]

```js
<MantineProvider withCSSVariables
      theme={{
        globalStyles: (theme) => ({
           ':root': {
               ...(theme.colorScheme === 'dark'
                ? {'--app-primary-color': 'var(--mantine-color-green-3)'}
                : {'--app-primary-color': 'var(--mantine-color-green-8)'}
           }
        })
      }}>{children}</MantineProvider>
```

2. Add the color variables in tailwind.config file [https://tailwindcss.com/docs/theme#colors]

```js
theme: {
    colors: {
      'primaryColor': 'var(--app-primary-color)'
    }
}
```

3. Tailwind colors methods are now available with mantine theme
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tk5Rt.png)

You can discover the implementation of Theme [light/dark mode] using mantine & tailwind here: https://github.com/firecamp-dev/firecamp/blob/main/platform/firecamp-ui/src/components/theme/FirecampThemeProvider.tsx

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the answer with all relevant information. Make sure to use your own words, [answers comprised entirely of a quote (sourced or not) will often be deleted since they do not contain any original content](/help/referencing).